# Problem with manually updating matrix in a custom layer while implementing "Fast Weights"

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am really new to Tensorflow, but my end goal is to implement the architecture described in "Using Fast Weight to Attend to the Recent Past" in Tensorflow 2.0. 
I started off with a copy of a SimpleRNNCell from [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py) and my idea was to simply extend this SimpleRNN (Layer) into what I need. This extensions would not be a lot of effort, since it would only include
a) Initialising a matrix when the cell is created (with zeros),

b) Manually updating this matrix in the call() function.  (this is done by simple building the output product of the recurrent layers activation and adding it to the to the matrix in question),

c) Adding it onto the normal reservoir activity.

My Problem is that when trying to manually updating this matrix, I get presented the following error:

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: add_1
```

The thing I tried basically boil down to what kind of matrix I initialise; I tried initialising it as
a) a weight, that is not trainable (`self.add_weight()`)
b) a constant (`tensorflow.python.keras.backend.constant()`)
c) a tensor (`tensorflow.python.keras.backend.variable()`)

- Initialisation of the matrix:

```
self.A = K.variable(value=tf.zeros((self.units, self.units)),
        dtype='float32', name='fast_weights')
```

- Manual update

```
self.A = self.l * self.A + self.e * K.dot(K.transpose(h), h)
```

, where h is the activation of the hidden, recurrent layer. This is where the error is thrown.

- Addition to update step:

```
h = self.activation(K.bias_add(K.dot(inputs, self.kernel), self.bias) + K.dot(h, self.recurrent_kernel)) + K.dot(h, self.A)
```

where `K.dot(h, self.A)` is what I added.

I have the feeling (and I hope) that I am missing something obvious. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use old tf.assign to overcome this issue.

```
self.A = tf.compat.v1.assign(self.A, self.l * self.A + self.e * K.dot(K.transpose(h), h))
```